# How to pass data to a class based view's method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to figure out how I can pass data from a form to the method of a class based view that serves as a API endpoint.

Homepage view (has a form to enter a stock ticker):

```
def home(request):

# data = get_stock_data('TSLA', key)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TickerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ticker = form.cleaned_data['ticker']
        stock_data = get_stock_data(ticker, api_key)
        return redirect('chart-data', ticker=ticker) # this line I am having trouble with

else:
    form = TickerForm()
    stock_data = None

return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'data': stock_data, 'form':form})
```

The API View:

```
class ChartData(APIView):

authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []

def get(self, request, ticker, format=None):
    # get stock data
    stock_data = get_stock_data(ticker, api_key) # how do I pass the ticker?
    labels = []
    default_items = []
    # get label & values
    for key, value in stock_data.items():
        labels.append(key)
        default_items.append(value['4. close'])
    # prepare data
    data = {
        'labels': labels[::-1],
        'default_items': default_items[::-1]
    }
    return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.home, name="homepage"),
   path('api/chart/data', views.ChartData.as_view(), name="chart-data"),
]
```

Then I get the data with Javascript and display the graph on the frontend, which works fine. The only thing I can't figure out how to pass the ticker argument to the get method of my ChartData view. I hope my problem is clear.

Comment: Is there any errors you are getting with that code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   return redirect('chart-data', {'ticker':ticker})
```

Have to use a dictionary, I believe ...

Comment: You are probably thinking of `django.urls.reverse`. `django.shortcuts.redirect` works differently, but will pass any named arguments to `reverse()` as `kwargs={...}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `ticker` in the url path.

```
path('api/chart/data/<slug:ticker>/', views.ChartData.as_view(), name="chart-data"),
```

This assumes `ticker` is a string like 'TSLA'.